# Batch file to insert multiple registry entries and log results of each to file

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, registry

I'm looking for a little advise and help.

I have a script which inserts into registry a number of values.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" /f /v "SystemID" /t REG_SZ /d "%SystemID%"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" /f /v "Servername" /t REG_SZ /d "%Servername%"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" /f /v "NIC01_IPv6" /t REG_SZ /d "%NIC01_IPv6%"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" /f /v "NIC01_GWv6" /t REG_SZ /d "%NIC01_GWv6%"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" /f /v "NIC02_IPv6" /t REG_SZ /d "%NIC02_IPv6%"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" /f /v "NIC02_GWv6" /t REG_SZ /d "%NIC02_GWv6%"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" /f /v "NIC03_IPv6" /t REG_SZ /d "%NIC03_IPv6%"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" /f /v "NIC03_GWv6" /t REG_SZ /d "%NIC03_GWv6%"
```

I am looking for the best way to write individual results to a log file per registry entry, either OK or ERROR (for example)

I've looked a number of alternative methods, using "import *.reg" and using a %ERRORLEVEL% to write to log file but this is only on mass, I'm keen to keep to individual results per key.

Any ideas what's best suggestions here?

Appreciate any advise.
Thanks
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a list of `value` and `data` pairs then process it, analyze the `errorlevel` and print the status to a log file:

```
>"logfile.txt" (
    for %%L in (
        "SystemID %SystemID%"
        "Servername %Servername%"
        "NIC01_IPv6 %NIC01_IPv6%"
        "NIC01_GWv6 %NIC01_GWv6%"
        "NIC02_IPv6 %NIC02_IPv6%"
        "NIC02_GWv6 %NIC02_GWv6%"
        "NIC03_IPv6 %NIC03_IPv6%"
        "NIC03_GWv6 %NIC03_GWv6%"
    ) do for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ("%%~L") do (
        reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" ^
            /f /v "%%a" /t REG_SZ /d "%%b" >nul
        if errorlevel 1 (echo ERROR: %%a = %%b) else (echo OK: %%a = %%b)
    )
)
```

Or use only the names list with delayed expansion if none of the values can have `!` character:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>"logfile.txt" (
    for %%a in (
        SystemID
        Servername
        NIC01_IPv6
        NIC01_GWv6
        NIC02_IPv6
        NIC02_GWv6
        NIC03_IPv6
        NIC03_GWv6
    ) do (
        reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Configure" ^
            /f /v "%%a" /t REG_SZ /d "!%%a!" >nul
        if errorlevel 1 (echo ERROR: %%a = !%%a!) else (echo OK: %%a = !%%a!)
    )
)
```

Comment: Looks great! thank you i'll give it a go later when i get home.

Comment: I've had a chance to play with this now, works a treat - thank you.

Not that i need it but is it possible to also echo to cmd?

Comment: Yes, duplicate the `if ... echo` line and use output redirection: method 1) remove the overall redirection and put it to the echo command using `>>` like `(if ....... (echo...) else (echo...)) >> file` or method 2) leave the overall redirection but on the copied line redirect to `>con` (console).

Comment: Cheers Wox, i tried this lastnight before you posted - must have had a typo cos it's working today #lackofsleep

thanks mate!

Comment: Now I'm awake, is there any way to throw an error if the reg query results in a blank? - clearly the code above relies on a value being set, allowing it to be inserted into another set of Keys - however, if the source value is blank it will break the rest of what i have planned.

Therefore, if source value is blank, throw error - is this possible?

Comment: Why not? Anyway this is another question.

Comment: Suppose it is, at some point in the process i need to perform a sanity check on values, if there are any blanks the script needs to error and abort. 

I was thinking of doing that here, perhaps i should do this earlier in script - ok, thinking about it whilst typing makes me believe the sanity check must occur much earlier..  

nice, ok.. cheers!